# Live validation message in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

I was making a register page in my django project and i wanted to display a error message until conditions like username/email is taken are false
I used the messages.info to store the messages that I later output in my html page but the messages don't load or reset until I refresh the page
I wrote this code in the views.py file:

```
def register(request):
 if request.method == 'POST':
     username = request.POST['username']
     email = request.POST['email']
     password = request.POST['password']
     password2 = request.POST['password2']

     if password == password2:
         if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
             messages.info(request,'Username Taken')
             return redirect('')
         elif User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
             messages.info(request,'Email Taken')
             return redirect('')
         else:    
             user = User.objects.create_user(username= username,password=password2,email=email)
             user.save()
     else:
         messages.info(request,'Passwords Dont Match')
     return redirect('/')`enter code here
 else:`enter code here`
     return render(request,'register.html')
```

Comment: Then you should make an AJAX call for that.

Comment: this happens when you dont provide proper redirect url that matches reverse urls

Comment: try giving name attribute of urls.py in redirect like redirect('home'),redirect('dashboard') somthing like that which you use in your urls.py

Comment: Do things the Django way: use a Django form, and rerender your template until the form validates. You will also gain proper data validation and sanitization, useful error messages in the form itself etc. Oh and yes; you certainly __dont__ want to store passwords in clear !!!